# Taking Screenshot

Tags: android, path, screenshot, paint, android-canvas

I'm developing an application for taking screenshots in the device. In this application, we can draw anything on the screen. For this I am using Canvas, Paint and Path to do this.

I'm using this code to take screenshots:

```
        public void saveScreenshot() 
    {
        if (ensureSDCardAccess()) 
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            onDraw(canvas);
            File file = new File(mScreenshotPath + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("Panel", "FileNotFoundException", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Panel", "IOEception", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to ensure that the given path exists.
     * TODO: check external storage state
     */
    private boolean ensureSDCardAccess() {
        File file = new File(mScreenshotPath);
        if (file.exists()) {
            return true;
        } else if (file.mkdirs()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

However, when the following line is run:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

my application closes with the following exception:

```
11-28 15:05:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(8209): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
```

If I change the height and width, the screenshot is taken, but it's empty:

[image: Empty]

Why is that happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you calling saveScreenshot?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra That's my method name. Is there any problem with that method name?

Comment: I asked where have you called SaveScreenshot function? Is it in onCreate(), onResume()?

Comment: No, i've create menu option. And, i'm calling there.

Comment: I think you just do not get the right width and height of the layout, you can get it in onLayout method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it like this,

Give the id for your main Layout & after you display the content on the screen write the below code on some Listener say button click or menu item or any such Listener(make sure you call these line after your layout is display else it will give a blank screen).

```
        View content = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        getScreen(content);
```

method getScreen(content)

```
private void getScreen(View content)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
        File file = new File("/sdcard/test.png");
        try 
        {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
            ostream.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Also don't for to add permission for writing file to SDCard.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
                                                               </uses-permission>
```

Comment: +1, now can take screen shot of any single view/layout of my screen.. by passing it as view.

Answer (score 3):

Exception is because the height and width of `Bitmap` you are creating is **zero**

try below code to get height and width

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

In case there is no access to `getWindowManager`

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Comment: yes, your second method is working. It's takes empty screenshot but, i've written "android" text on the screen.

Comment: That is not related to this question there is problem with yur draw method

Comment: For that post a seprate question posting you onDraw and onTouch code

Comment: display.getWidth() and display.getHeight() are the wrong thing to use; these return the real size of the overall display, which has no required relationship to the actual size of your UI in the display.

Answer (score 0):

getWidth(), getHeight() required to be called with context, if your are trying it outside Activity it will fail. Try getApplicationContext.getWidth().

Answer (score 0):

Could you show more of your code pls? It seems like you are calling width and height have not positive integer values. You could debug this by printing the values of width and height.

Comment: ok. Can u print out the values of width and height just to see what they contain after initialization?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and the solution was:

You get width and heigh before your view is drown so check first if width or heigh equal zero:

```
if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            initRemote(remote);
            isViewInitialized=false;
        }
```

isViewInitialized is a member value.

Then put this code in OnSizeChanged

```
@Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if(!isViewInitialized&&){
            // this is the right place to take snapshot :)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have wrapped the screenshot code into a very simple library. It allows you to take screenshots and store them to the disk if you want.

https://github.com/abdallahalaraby/Blink