# Creating a Bitmap of a View

Tags: android, view, bitmap

I try to create a View programaticaly by inflating an layout.

```
View marker = ((LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.overlay_view, null);
```

Now i want to convert this View to a Bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);

        Bitmap cache = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cache);
        view.draw(canvas);

        return cache;
    }
```

I also tried measure(1, 1) and layout(0 ,0 ,0 ,0) without any changes. 
The Bitmap looks like the filled layout.
Now the Problem: If i put something into the View thats makes the View bigger than the Displaysize in width or height (example: a TextView with a long text), the Bitmap is also bigger. 
The Views XML width and height is WRAP_CONTENT but it didnt works.
I never put this View somewhere to display it (becouse i only need the Bitmap).

Question: How can i WRAP the View to a maximum of width = displayWidth?

I tried view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParam(100, 100)) but it was also bigger than 100?! I really dont understand whats happened, when i inflate the layout and set the content of the View.

The view.getMeasuredWidth and Height is always bigger as my display?! (if i put something bigger in it)

Here is an Example of the Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/somedrawable"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:clickable="true">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294110/taking-screenshot/8366223#8366223)

Comment: hum? Where is the answer? There was an answer but it is gone now?!

Comment: check the link that I had given.

Comment: ah i see... okay. I also tried the getDrawableCache stuff in all different variations and it didnt work. If i use this cache, the bitmap is empty! If i use view.layout(0,0,100,100) the getDrawingCache returns a Bitmap with width 100 and height 100 but i can see nothing, so it is empty.

Comment: It might be null because you are setting cache before the screen layout load(onCreate) so try setting the cache after your screen load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

first step: add new LayoutParams to the view. This is important, becouse without you will get a NullPointer.

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Second:

```
view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(displayMetrics.widthPixels), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
             MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(displayMetrics.heightPixels, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
```

for `view.measure()` i used `MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(displayMetrics.heightPixels, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));`. First parameter is the display width or heigt and the second is the mode AT_MOST, this is needed to "wrap" the View.

Works great! (for me :p )