# Android: How can I capture current fullscreen using canvas

Tags: android, canvas, screen

Somebody please help me with this, I have tried capturing fullscreen without canvas and I get a black screen image each time. Another interesting thing I have found is that when I open that image on a mobile and delete it, then another screen with an image appears. How it happened I don't know as I am new in android app development.

Can anyone please help me find a solution to this?

Comment: You may want to make your question more open-ended. Even though when you tried it without canvas it didn't work, you should state what happened, what the problem was, and if there's any way to solve your problem, and then state what you want to try. Don't limit yourself to a single solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

A quick search here in SO gave me this which has an accepted answer. You might want to look at it.
SO Source:
[Taking Screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294110/taking-screenshot)

Quoting:

You can do it like this,

Give the id for your main Layout & after you display the content on the screen write the below code on some Listener say button click or menu item or any such Listener(make sure you call these line after your layout is display else it will give a blank screen).

```
    View content = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    getScreen(content);
    method getScreen(content)

    private void getScreen(View content)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
            File file = new File("/sdcard/test.png");
            try 
            {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                ostream.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Also don't for to add permission for writing file to SDCard.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
                                                                   </uses-permission>
```

Comment: I think this only captures the actual View; any Dialogs/AlertDialogs that are there as "popups" are not captured...